# Query for two tables with similar information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on some baseball stats to improve my database abilities I have data for hitters from 2017 and 2018 MLB seasons. what I hope to accomplish is to average the number of games played, at bats and hit over the two seasons. Eventually I want to do it over five seasons but I figure I need to start somewhere. The problem is that both tables have exactly the same names for the columns. I think I need to do a UNION but I am not sure.

I am using SSMS, the Express version.
I have tried a simple query, thinking it would do some thing but obviously, I should have known better. I tried:

```
SELECT PLAYER, g, ab, hit
FROM mlb_2017, mlb_2018
WHERE mlb_2017.PLAYER = mlb_2018.PLAYER
ORDER BY PLAYER;
```

this is the Excel file example. Both 2017 and 2018 have these fields exactly as shown, well, with about ten more fields that I am not using yet.

```
Player  Team    pos g   ab  hit 2b
abreu,jose  whit    1B  128 499 132 36
acuna,ron   brav    OF  111 433 127 26
adames,will rays    SS  85  288 80  7
adams,lane  brav    OF  26  25  6   1
```

So what I want, is to combine both of the seasons into one two year total and then average them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a union query:

```
SELECT PLAYER, AVG(hit) AS avg_hits
FROM
(
    SELECT PLAYER, hit
    FROM mlb_2017
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PLAYER, hit
    FROM mlb_2018
) t
GROUP BY PLAYER;
```

The idea behind the union query is that it brings the hit data for each player, for both 2017 and 2018, into a single intermediate table, which we can then aggregate to find the averages.

Comment: One more question, what does the 't' after the close parenthesis do?

Comment: `t` is an alias, which is required in order to identify the intermediate table created.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to approach this structurally is to change your ETL process so you load them into a single table and, at the time of loading, add an attribute (set from the file/source) of 'year'.

This gives you the flexibility to write statements that are year specific (where year = x) or do simple count/sum aggregate functions with a group by :)

Comment: I was thinking that and it wouldn't be too difficult just not what I had hoped for. I guess as I added years it would be simpler to just have five rows of data for each player versus five tables to deal with. Also could do some visualizations easier. Thank you

Comment: It depends where you want the pain to be :) usually you load once and query often so do the hard bit up front! :D

Comment: While not providing a direct answer, this is a good suggestion IMHO +1.